# World Cup 2014: How many possibilities were there for the participants of the round of 16?

Tags: probability-theory

> 32 nations participated in the World Cup 2014 in Brazil.
>
> How many possibilities were there for the participants of the round of 16?

I am not quite sure how to understand this question, but I believe it is meant how many possibilities there were for choosing 16 nations out of 32 nations. On an intuitive basis, I would have said that this is the number

$${32 \choose 16}.$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Isn't the round of 16 a knockout stage? But the question is still quite unclear as the number of matches in round of $16$ is obviosly $8$, but if a team wins they have one more "opportunity".

Comment: Since I had to translate this question (although it was written poorly anyway): I believe it could also be meant how many possibilities there are for 16 teams being in the round of 16, so in how many ways these 32 teams could end up as 16 teams.

Comment: I rephrased the question.

Comment: Then $\binom{32}{16}$ is correct assuming you are not concerned with whether a team that qualified, finished at the top of its group or runners-up; the answer would be $\binom{\textrm{no. of teams in a group}}{2}$ times the number of groups if you are given a fixed set of groups(and top $2$ from each qualify.).